# ansible user module always shows changed

Tags: ansible

I'm struggling to properly use ansible's user module. The problem is every time I run my playbook, the users I created **always** show as changed, even if I have already created them.

[I found other people with the same issue here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/6854), though I am struggling to actually fix it based on the github thread. Probably the most helpful comment that I didn't understand

> I can confirm that it only looked like a bug - adding the append
>   option to two tasks made it so that they're not always undoing the
>   work of the other, and fixed the permanently changed trigger. I did
>   not need to add "group:"

This is what my playbook looks like:

```
- name: Generate all users for the environment
  user:
    createhome: yes
    state: present # to delete
    name: "{{ item.user }}"
    groups: "{{ 'developers' if item.role == 'developer' else 'customers' }}"
    password: "{{ generic_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    append: yes
  with_items:
    - "{{ users }}"
```

My intention is the have every user belong to their own private group (User Private Groups) but also have a developer belong to the developers group. **With the current configuration currently it works, with the problem being ansible always reports the user as "changed"**. I'll then add the `developers` group to the sudoers file; hence I'd like to add the user to the `developers` group.

e.g.

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:/home$ sudo su - nick
$ pwd
/home/nick
$ touch file.txt
$ ls -al
-rw-rw-r--  1 nick nick    0 Jul  3 12:06 file.txt

vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:/home$ cat /etc/group | grep 'developers'
developers:x:1002:nick,ldnelson,greg,alex,scott,jupyter
```

Here is the verbose output running against vagrant locally for one of the users:

```
changed: [192.168.33.10] => (item={'user': 'nick', 'role': 'developer', 'with_ga': False}) => {
    "append": true,
    "changed": true,
    "comment": "",
    "group": 1004,
    "groups": "developers",
    "home": "/home/nick",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "append": true,
            "comment": null,
            "create_home": true,
            "createhome": true,
            "expires": null,
            "force": false,
            "generate_ssh_key": null,
            "group": null,
            "groups": [
                "developers"
            ],
            "hidden": null,
            "home": null,
            "local": null,
            "login_class": null,
            "move_home": false,
            "name": "nick",
            "non_unique": false,
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "password_lock": null,
            "remove": false,
            "seuser": null,
            "shell": null,
            "skeleton": null,
            "ssh_key_bits": 0,
            "ssh_key_comment": "ansible-generated on ubuntu-bionic",
            "ssh_key_file": null,
            "ssh_key_passphrase": null,
            "ssh_key_type": "rsa",
            "state": "present",
            "system": false,
            "uid": null,
            "update_password": "always"
        }
    },
    "item": {
        "role": "developer",
        "user": "nick",
        "with_ga": false
    },
    "move_home": false,
    "name": "nick",
    "password": "NOT_LOGGING_PASSWORD",
    "shell": "/bin/sh",
    "state": "present",
    "uid": 1002
}
```

Should be unrelated, but I am adding some to the developers group as I intend to grant sudo access for certain commands.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`generic_password | password_hash('sha512')` is not idempotent. Salt of the hash changes each time the filter [*password_hash*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#hashing-and-encrypting-strings-and-passwords) runs.

To make it idempotent, either run it with a specific salt

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.user:
    name: nick
    password: "{{ generic_password | password_hash('sha512', 'mysalt') }}"
```

, or update the password [*on_create*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#parameter-update_password)

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.user:
    name: nick
    password: "{{ generic_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    update_password: on_create
```

(, or register the [return values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html#return-values) and declare [changed_when](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#overriding-the-changed-result)).

---

Consider external management of passwords e.g. [Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#encrypting-content-with-ansible-vault) or [Passwordstore](https://www.passwordstore.org/). There is a lookup plugin for *passwordstore*. See *`ansible-doc -t lookup passwordstore`*. See also my implementation of [Passwordstore](https://ansible-linux-postinstall.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide-task-passwords-passwordstore.html).