# Adding users in ansible and enforcing password change, resets user's password when adding new user

Tags: ansible

I am having problems with Ansible and adding new users to servers.
Firstly I check if the users are present on the system and if not, then I proceed to create them.

I found a somewhat similar problem here: [ansible user module always shows changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869949/ansible-user-module-always-shows-changed)
and I was able to fix the changed status when adding a new user in the file userlist with adding a simple salt.
However, the last part, which is the handler, is always performed.

This is how my playbook looks like:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - /home/ansible/userlist

  tasks:

    # check if user exists in system, using the username 
    # and trying to search inside passwd file
    - name: check user exists  
      getent:
        database: passwd
        key: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      register: userexists
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: add user if it does not exit
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        password: "{{ 'password' | password_hash('sha512', 'mysecretsalt')  }}"
        update_password: on_create
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      when: userexists is failed
      notify: change password

  handlers:

    - name: change user password upon creation
      shell: chage -d 0 "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      listen: change password
```

And here is the simple file called userlist:

```
users:
- testuser1
- testuser2
- testuser3
- testuser22
```

When I am running the playbook without changes to the userlist file, everything is fine.
However, if I add a new user to the file, then, when an existing user tries to log in, the system enforces them to change their password, because the handler is always called.
Is there any way to alter the code in a way that the enforcing of changing the password immediately is only performed on newly created users?

Comment: You can use block and rescue. Please find an example here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892455/ansible-execute-task-or-handler-if-any-task-failed

Comment: So, from what I understood, I should try to loop within a block statement, and when the user fails the rescue task will be called. However, in the above example, how can I change the code so that the command ```chage -d 0 "{{ item }}"``` will only be run on the "failed" user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 main issues in your playbook:

1. `userexists` is registering each result individually, but you are referencing only the overall "failure" result. Use a `debug` statement to show the variable to see what I mean
2. If the handler is notified, you are looping on all users, rather than only those that have "changed" (i.e. have been created)

There's a couple of different approaches to fix this, but I think this might be the most succinct:

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: add user if it does not exist
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        password: "{{ 'password' | password_hash('sha512', 'mysecretsalt')  }}"
        update_password: on_create
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      register: useradd
      notify: change password

  handlers:
    - name: change user password upon creation
      shell: chage -d 0 {{ item.name }}
      loop: "{{ useradd.results }}"
      when: item.changed
      listen: change password
```

Comment: Thank you so much, mate! I tested some things and it seems to work.
Just quick question. On the handler, you are looping the useradd, which was registered on the previous task, and then you are only executing it when it's changed, correct? Can I print the value of the item.name? I tried with useradd.results.name but it's not working. In any case, thank you for the help! Cheers!

Comment: Yes the handler will only execute if at least one new user has been added. The handler will then loop on all users but only update password expiry for users registered as "changed". The reason you cannot print `useradd.results.name` is that `useradd.results` is a list. You would need to use it in a loop and print `item.name`, or address individual entries like `useradd.results[0].name`